# Help with a non-linear partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am wondering whether someone can help me with a non-linear PDE:

$$\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2} = c\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2} \left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} \right)^{n-1}$$

where, $\phi(x,t)$ is a function of $x$ and $t$, and $c$ and $n$ are constants ($c$ has dependency on $n$). This is not a homework problem and I am not a professional mathematician. I would appreciate any help! Even conjectures will help! thanks,

Comment: A trivial remark: linear functions are solution, i.e. $\phi(x,t)=A+Bx+Ct$ is a solution, where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are constants.

Comment: @newbee:  great question for a first-timer, +1!  Would love to hear some background information, where you got this equation, is it related to some physics problem, *und so weiter*!

Comment: @Paul, yes I have noticed that, but it is not very helpful for me. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: @Robert Lewis It is actually related to a non-linear dynamical problem I am simulating. This is the Euler-Lagrange equation for that system. I have searched a lot, but couldn't find this equation anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: @Newbee:  very interesting!  Could you be more specific?  How does it arise as an Euler -Lagrange equation?  From what?  Can you provide any citings, references and/or links to relevant material.  If you can, it would be much appreciated by yours truly.  Thanks, Bob Lewis

Comment: @Newbee:  could it be related to the porous medium equation?  I dunno, looks sorta familiar/recognizable . . .

Comment: This might be a trivial addition to the above question, but a more compact form may strike a few more ideas. $$
\frac{\partial^{2}\phi}{\partial t^{2}}\;=\;\frac{c}{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\right)^{n}
$$ I for one do not recognise this equation from any of the nonlinear pdes I have worked on personally.